# git, setting up remote repository without ssh

Tags: ssh, git

I want to set up a remote git repository on a openSuse machine, and I have the following question.

Do I really need ssh on the machine, to set up the remote git repository? Initially is it possible to set it up without ssh?

Comment: You don't need ssh, but ssh isn't a complication: in fact, it can make setting up git easier. This depends on who should have access to the git repository. Is this just for you? Public? Something in between? Who can commit, and who can clone?

Answer (score 2):

SSH is useful when you want to working in that machine remotely. So, you can fix, troubleshoot without getting in front monitor. Usually SSH is installed when you install OS. So, what's your concern about running SSH server in a machine?

As explained in [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), to setup a repository you have at least 4 alternative. Each item has its pros and cons.

1. SSH (no additional daemon, permission issue)
2. Git daemon (fastest remote data transfer, lack authentication)
3. HTTP(s) (used with proxy, HTTP overhead)
4. Local